# Acivity monitoring and position settings not retained

Tags: settings, google-fit

I am a final user of the Fit app, but support for it is maintained here.

I have a problem on my Pixel 7a: even if I turn on Activity monitoring and position option in app settings, they get off again after a few seconds.
I also use Health Connect, do not know if this helps.

What can I try to make my settings persistent?

Thank you,
Matteo